# Uso de "vianda" en Puerto Rico

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, sustantivos, comida, puerto-rico

Esta pregunta en realidad debería titularse "¿Qué dice la abuela en [aquel rap de Winfred y la Ganga](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbEVRVozf7M) de finales de los 80?".

En 1989 el mundo recibió una buena dosis de español de Puerto Rico con la canción "Mi abuela" del grupo Wilfred y la Ganga, considerada como el primer rap en español que tuvo éxito mundial. Como hablante de español europeo, muchas expresiones nos sorprendieron pero alguna incluso nos dejó sumidos en un misterio, como el verso que decía:

> No, no, no señor, yo no cocino porquerías.
>   Aquí se come ??? y arroz con habichuelas.

Parecía que decía "vianda" pero su significado (tal y como se conoce en España) no acababa de encajar, y algunos incluso pensaban que decía "mierda" lo cual tenía aún menos sentido.

Hoy, casi 30 años más tarde, vamos a intentar dar solución a este misterio. En algunas páginas de letras de canciones curiosamente esta palabra la marcan como dudosa, y en otras sí que se afirma que dice "vianda". El *Diccionario de americanismos* nos ayuda con la siguiente [acepción para Puerto Rico](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=vianda):

> Tubérculos y frutos comestibles puestos a la mesa cocidos o fritos.

Esta definición aparece también [en el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=birftrn) pero marcada como de uso en las Antillas. La definición encaja con el contexto, pero en todo caso se me queda un poco escasa. ¿Sirve cualquier tubérculo? ¿Cualquier fruto comestible? ¿Cuentan las frutas? ¿Una "vianda" sería un plato principal o un acompañamiento?

Así pues, pregunto: ¿qué se considera exactamente una "vianda" en Puerto Rico? ¿Ha cambiado su uso desde finales de los 80 hasta hoy? ¿Es una palabra de uso común o es más de abuela?

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Qué se considera exactamente una "vianda" en Puerto Rico? ¿Ha cambiado su uso desde finales de los 80 hasta hoy? ¿Es una palabra de uso común o es más de abuela?

A juzgar por las recetas de cocina en el internet, sí es de uso común actual.

Algunos explican el término así: *root vegetables* (**tubérculos**), y ciertas otras cosas también (e.g. "*Vianda* is a starchy tropical root or tuber such as yucca, yautia, cassava, malanga, taro and sweet potatoes, green plantains are also included" -- [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vianda)).  Pero lo que todas las viandas tienen en común es **el almidón**, por lo que el término más apto sería **verduras feculentas de las zonas tropicales** o ***starchy tropical vegetables***.  (Nótese que la zanahoria no pertenece a este conjunto de alimentos.)

Como documentación escojí dos artículos impresos.  Notas: Creo que la *batata* es el camote (en inglés, *sweet potato* o *yam*); el *plátano* se refiere a lo que se tiene que cocer (en inglés *plantain*, en México *plátano macho*), a diferencia de la *banana*, que se come crudo (en México, *plátano roatán*); la *calabaza* se refiere al *winter squash* de inglés, a diferencia del *summer squash* o *zucchini* de inglés (que se conoce como *calabacita* en México).

[La versatilidad de las viandas](https://www.sal.pr/2017/11/16/la-versatilidad-de-las-viandas/)

> **Yuca, yautía, calabaza, batata, ñame, plátano, malanga, pana, papa**… Son algunas de las viandas más utilizadas en la isla y una de
>   las opciones de alimentación que ha estado en nuestro menú, con
>   algunas variaciones y añadiduras, desde tiempos inmemoriales. Son
>   accesibles, económicas y una solución rápida, ya sean solas o como
>   acompañantes.
>
> “Las viandas son de los alimentos más versátiles que tenemos. Además,
>   son nutritivas, fáciles de conseguir, se mantienen por mucho tiempo
>   sin refrigeración y hay muchas maneras de confeccionar diversos
>   platillos”, afirma el chef Carlos Ríos, del restaurante criollo
>   Delicias, en el Hotel La Concha, en Condado.
>
> Desde sopas, puré ligero, un majado más compacto, mofongos, chips, en
>   escabeche, pasteles, alcapurrias, rellenos y diversidad de frituras,
>   cremas, panes, casabe, bizcochos, tostones y hasta flanes. Solo es
>   cuestión de poner la creatividad a trabajar para lograr algo diferente
>   y sabroso. Sobre todo, en estos momentos en que son muchos los que
>   cocinan con una estufita de gas.
>
> “Las viandas pueden estar fuera de refrigerador por bastante tiempo
>   sin dañarse, así que ahora que muchos no tienen electricidad, son una
>   gran alternativa. Además, son alimentos que nunca pasan de moda, por
>   eso su uso nunca decae en los hogares puertorriqueños”, afirma Ríos,
>   quien dice que en el restaurante donde trabaja “las viandas son unos
>   de mis elementos más importantes en el menú”.
>
> Y aunque generalmente son acompañantes de platos como en el caso de la
>   ensalada de bacalao o como parte de un sancocho o sopa, también tienen
>   su protagonismo en la cocina. Por ejemplo, el chef indica que hace
>   ñoquis de papa, yuca o yautía y que puede convertirse en la “estrella
>   del plato”.
>
> Además, destaca que hacer ñoquis de una vianda dice que no es difícil.
>   “Lo que haces es que la hierves -o la puedes rostizar-, se maja y
>   cuando la masa está fría, incorporas el huevo, la harina y parmesano
>   para hacer una masa”, explica Ríos, quien hace la salvedad de que si
>   los haces de yuca, debes tener en cuenta que tiene bastante almidón,
>   por lo que éste se debe sacar para que no queden demasiado densos los
>   ñoquis. Pero de la misma forma, agrega que ese almidón se puede
>   utilizar para espesar ya sea en una sopa o una salsa. “Es lo que ayuda
>   a espesar el sancocho, un plato muy típico de aquí, que gusta mucho
>   todo el año”, añade.
>
> Ríos también menciona el escabeche de viandas o el majado, como platos
>   que se pueden servir solos o con algún acompañante. “Un majado no
>   tiene que llevar una carne. Puede tener vegetales o un crocante de
>   otra vianda”, propone el chef, mientras recomienda que para el
>   escabeche se deben picar en pedazos pequeños y hervirlas con un poco
>   de sal.
>
> “Luego se dejan enfriar y se hace el escabeche, que se compone de
>   cebolla, aceitunas, lasquitas de ajo, hojas de laurel y pimienta
>   negra. Lo más importante es el vinagre y el aceite de oliva. Todo eso
>   se pone a cocinar y cuando esté hirviendo se incorpora a las viandas.
>   Yo lo dejo marinar por 24 horas para que todos los sabores se mezclen
>   bien y la vianda coja ese sabor tan rico”, explica tras aceptar que la
>   malanga, la yautía y la yuca son sus viandas preferidas y las que más
>   utiliza en su cocina.
>
> La yautía, de hecho, es uno de los tubérculos que cobran protagonismo
>   en casi todos los hogares boricuas a lo largo de todo el año. “Me
>   encanta por su variedad. La incluyo en casi todos los platos, hasta
>   para postres, porque hago un flan que hacía mi abuela con yautía lila,
>   que tiene un sabor ligero, un poco dulce, pero sin llegar a serlo por
>   completo”, agrega el chef, aunque dice que la batata dulce también es
>   ideal para hacer flan “y queda espectacular”.

[Sabrosuras: Majado de viandas](http://www.presenciapr.com/majado-de-viandas/)

> 8 oz (media libra) de viandas (por ejemplo: **malanga, yuca, ñame,
>   yautía, papa, batata**)
>
> 1 taza de leche entera o evaporada   2 cucharadas de aceite oliva
>   Sal y pimienta a gusto   Una cucharada de perejil picadito para
>   adornar
>
> En una cacerola grande, poner 8 tazas de agua a hervir con una
>   cucharada de sal. Pelar y picar las viandas en cubos de no más de 2
>   pulgadas y verter en agua hirviendo hasta que se cuezan (que un
>   tenedor penetre la vianda sin resistencia y fácilmente). Esto puede
>   tomar de 12-25 minutos dependiendo del tamaño que cortó la vianda.
>
> Remover las viandas del agua y verter en un recipiente mediano junto
>   al aceite y la leche (comenzar con 1/2 taza y luego seguir
>   incorporando más leche hasta que tome la consistencia preferida),
>   majar con majador de papas o tenedor, ajustar sazón con sal y pimienta
>   y esparcir el perejil sobre el majado. Servir. ¡Yum!

Comment: Buenísimo punto, respeto al almidón. Supongo que así se mantienen enteras las cosas después de cocerse.

Comment: @AaronBrick - No entiendo.  Si no se deja en la lumbre demasiado tiempo, los trozos se mantienen en trozos. // El almidón también se conoce como *carbohidrato complejo*.

Comment: Quise decir que las verduras sin tanto almidón se deshacen mas rapidamente en el sartén. Quizás no es así de verdad.

Comment: @AaronBrick - Bueno, todo lo relacionado con la comida es difícil de discutir a nivel internacional, porque el significado de los términos varía tanto de un país a otro.  Cuando veo "sartén," imagino que los ingredientes se están friendo.  Pero en todas las recetas de "viandas" que leí, se trataba de cocer con agua, no de freír. // Es interesante lo que dices.  No sé, habría que ver la bioquímica de los diferentes grupos.  Sospecho que lo que más resiste es la fibra (la celulosa), no el almidón.  Quizás se podría preguntar en https://cooking.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

*Vianda* sí existe en español, adoptado directamente del frances *viande* (comida, especificamente carne). Quizás ya perdió su referencia a la carne, porque el DRAE da:

> 1. f. Sustento y comida de los racionales.
> 2. f. Comida que se sirve a la mesa.
> 3. f. Ant. Frutos y tubérculos comestibles que se sirven guisados, como el ñame, la malanga, el plátano, etc.

Se nota que hay toda una clase de ingredientes que pueden considerarse vianda en Puerto Rico. El Tesoro Lexicográfico del español de Puerto Rico nos dice que es sinónimo de *verdura*. Las aceptaciones siguen:

> 1. (Ant.).  Frutos y tubérculos comestibles, como el ñame, el plátano, la yuca, la yautía, la batata, la calabaza y la malanga, que se suelen poner cocidos o fritos en la mesa. Ac. “Y llevar al pueblo las viandas que se cosechan en la tala.” Juan B. Huyke, Estímulos, 1922, p. 110.
> 2. Fruto o tubérculo comestible.
> 3. Vegetales del tipo de malanga, guineo, yautía, etc.
> 4. Al conjunto de varios de los frutos —batata, yautía, ñame, malanga, yuca, calabaza, y también el plátano y el piche ‘guineo verde’, que se consumen salcochados, se le aplica por campos y pueblos la mención colectiva genérica de viandas— y asimismo verduras.

Concluyo que el rap trata de cualquier de las variadas plantas que se preparan en la cocina boricua.

Answer (score 1):

Esto es pura conjetura, pero existe en inglés la palabra *viand*, que tiene origen latín y según dictionary.com se define como: [1]

> **noun**
>   1. an article of food.
>   2. *viands*, articles or dishes of food, now usually of a choice or delicate kind

Si *vianda* o *viandas* tiene el mismo significado en español, podría ser que la abuela se refiera a platos de calidad alta, en lugar de dichas *porquerías*.

[1] http://www.dictionary.com/browse/viand?s=t